# Plotting an Equation Using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics, parametric-functions

I'm trying to plot the solution of a set of differential equations and see how the solution changes when the value of a certain variable **de** is changed. The equations have solutions to the values of **de** which I have gotten individually using NDSolve but I am unable to replicate the result for all required values of **de** in one single program. I code I have written is:

```
om = 1;
k = 1;
L = 0.001;
P = 1.3;
eqns = {
a'[t] == I*((de/om)*a[t] - (b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]])*a[t] 
-1/2) - (k/(2*om))*a[t], 
b'[t] == -I*((P*(Abs[a[t]])^2)/2 + b[t]) - (L/(2*om))*b[t], 
b[0] == 0, a[0] == 0};
s = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, de, 
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
x[de] = b[de] + Conjugate[b[de]]
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[x[de][t] ], {t, 0, 99}, PlotRange 
-> All], {de, 0.1, 1}]
```

I have tried everything that I knew in my limited knowledge of Mathematica but I couldn't get a solution. I hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

om = 1;
k = 1;
L = 1/1000;
P = 13/10;

eqns = {a'[t] == 
    I*((de/om)*a[t] - (b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]])*a[t] - 1/2) - 
        (k/(2*om))*a[t], 
   b'[t] == -I*((P*(Abs[a[t]])^2)/2 + b[t]) - (L/(2*om))*b[t], 
   b[0] == 0, a[0] == 0};

s = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 100}, de, MaxSteps -> ∞];

x[de_?NumericQ][t_?NumericQ] = (b[de][t] + Conjugate[b[de][t]]) /. s;

Manipulate[
 Plot[x[de][t], {t, 0, 99}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}], {de, 0.1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
om = 1;
k = 1;
L = 0.001;
P = 1.3;
eqns = {a'[t] == 
    I*((de/om)*a[t] - (b[t] + Conjugate[b[t]])*a[t] - 
        1/2) - (k/(2*om))*a[t], 
   b'[t] == -I*((P*(Abs[a[t]])^2)/2 + b[t]) - (L/(2*om))*b[t], 
   b[0] == 0, a[0] == 0};
s = ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, de, 
   MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
x = b[t]/. s;
Manipulate[
 Plot[x[de]+Conjugate[x[de]], {t, 0, 99}, PlotRange -> All], {de, 
  0.1, 1}]
```

When solving equations, *Mathematica* always returns solutions as [substitution rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html), then you have to use the `/.` operator to get a working function.

Also, there is no need to write `[t]` when calling `x[de]` in the `Plot` command, as `x[*some value*]` returns `PInterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <>][t]`, which already has the `[t]` argument.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another variation that is somewhat more succinct than the other solutions.

```
m = 1;
k = 1;
L = 0.001;
P = 1.3;

pF = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, {a, b}, {t, 0, 100}, de];

Manipulate[
  With[{bF = pF[de][[2]]}, Plot[2 Re[bF[t]], {t, 0, 99}, PlotRange -> 4.1]],
  {de, .1, 1., .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

#### Notes

- `Reduce[z + Conjugate[z] == 2 Re[z], z]`

  > `True`
- Specifying 4.1 for the plot range, fixes the y-axis scale and better demonstrates the growth of the curve as the parameter `de` varies.